# What is the syntax for passing named parameters in MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, parameters, mariadb

I would expect from here...

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/user-defined-variables/ 
and here...
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html

that this would work (from python)...

```
conn.execute("select * from db.`My Table` where `my id` = @my_id",{'@my_id':54321}).fetchall()
```

but it doesn't.  I can get it working using the '%s' syntax, & passing in a list but I'd like named parameters.

Do I have to run

```
SET @my_id = 54321
```

first?  Do I have to use a stored proc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as it is on the same connection, you can execute `SET @my_id = 54321` followed by `select * from db.My Table where my id = @my_id`. Doing it that way, passing the value as a parameter in the .execute() shouldn't be needed.

Comment: True. But I am unaware of another way to get named variables like you are wanting. Other options only allow for %s or ?

Comment: So for those using this with pandas, as i am...        if conn.dialect.driver == 'mysqldb':
            for k,v in params.items():
                conn.execute("SET @{} = {}".format(k,v))

        if params:
            df = pd.read_sql(query, conn, params=params)

Comment: How elegant: Processing two statements to pass a value which is known on client side :-)